# PHP curl fetch doesn't see redirects

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I want to emulate the behaviour of [this](http://anyorigin.com/) tool, and I'm using the following code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
if(isset($_GET['get'])) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $_GET['get']
    ));
    curl_exec($curl);
}
```

Normally, it fetches me the HTML/data/whatever from the url specified in the GET parameter "get". Unfortunately, if I send it to a page that then redirects to another, it returns me nothing. For example, https://www.mediawiki.org/ redirects to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki; putting in the former url returns nothing, but putting in the latter one works. How do I make it see redirects and fetch me the data from the subsequent page? Somehow, anyorigin can do it.

Comment: You _did_ read the documentation of phps Curl extension, didn't you? Because that is answered in there.

Comment: It is? Silly me. Let me see...

Comment: Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and look for `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`...

Comment: @arkascha I only noticed your comment here after I posted my answer, no copying occured there.

Comment: @Dedee Such things happen. You can transfer the points you get to my bank account. Wait, I have the number somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

For cURL in PHP you must specify an option as follows

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```